# ReactiveUI Invoke Command on ViewModel when event fires in View

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am using the Reactive UI events expansion to Reactive UI.

Just playing around getting events to connect to the ViewModel.

Originally I had in my constructor of my View

```
        this.Events().KeyDown.Select(x => x.Key).InvokeCommand(ViewModel.NewTextCommand);
```

However, this has the issue in the constructor the view model does not exist yet. I considered adding a WhenAnyValue and setting up the Invoke but not sure if this could lead to memory leaks.

At the moment I have

```
        this.Events().KeyDown.Select(x => x.Key).Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                if (ViewModel != null)
                {
                    if (ViewModel.NewTextCommand.CanExecute(x))
                    {
                        ViewModel.NewTextCommand.Execute(x);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This seems a bit clumsy though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely use `WhenAnyValue`, but there's also a built-in `InvokeCommand` [overload](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L528) in ReactiveUI to do this:

```
this.Events().KeyDown.Select(x => x.Key).InvokeCommand(this, v => v.ViewModel.NewTextCommand);
```